# 'Boot' folder was accidentally deleted from WinServer 2008 R1

Tags: boot, bcdedit

Unfortunately, the 'Boot' folder in Windows Server 2008 R1 (not R2!) has been erroneously deleted. Now I'm seeng a message that Windows can't be started.

Fortunately, I have a copy of the whole disk on another physical disk. It's a week old, so I cannot just copy it back. How can I restore the 'Boot' folder? I've tried loading from a third disk and just copy the folder from the backup disk to the main system disk, but to no avail.

I know there is a command line utility `bootbcd`, but it seems to be included in Windows Server since 2008 R2. Also, I tried EasyBCD, but didn't understand how to apply it.

**UPDATE**

I can't find bootable OS DVD, so I can't repair the system that way.

Comment: Try this - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4162.windows-server-2008-repair-steps-for-no-boot-issues.aspx

Comment: @joeqwerty The question is updated.

Comment: You absolutely need the installation media.

Comment: Amendment to my comment based on your update: You need to get installation media. I don't see any other way to resolve this.

Comment: @joeqwerty What about 'bootbcd'? Isn't it supposed to copy from a source location to another disk? I just doesn't have it.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5023 for the trial version that should help repair. Also, i believe a Windows Vista version may also work with the repair your computer mode.